# Is there a way to get the index of the filtered array while filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable, idx, that controls the current index of an array of elements called items. While running a filter on this array, I want to change idx to current index of the filtered array if it matches a condition. Basically, I want the index to point to the same data before and after the filter.

This a simplified version of a webapp where users are shown lists of items and they can "pin" specific items so that every remaining list also contains that pinned item. Pinning an item sets the filter to that item. Only one list is shown at a time which is what idx represents.

```
let items = [
  [{/**/}, [1, 2, 3]],
  [{/**/}, [2, 2, 2]],
  [{/**/}, [3, 6, 0]],
  [{/**/}, [4, 7, 3]],
  [{/**/}, [5, 4, 9]],
  [{/**/}, [7, 1, 8]],
  [{/**/}, [8, 4, 4]],
  [{/**/}, [0, 7, 1]]
]

let idx = 5; //Current index
let curr = items[idx][1]; // Assume this is always up to date [7, 1, 8]
let filter = 1; // Data we want to filter for

// Filter items that contain the number 1
let filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
    if (!item[1].includes(filter))
        return false;
    if (item[1] == curr)
        idx = INDEX_IN_FILTERED_ARRAY(would be 1 in this case);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I think [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is a better fit than filter for your use.

Comment: @James - The OP won't have any array to call it on yet.

Comment: I've answered your actual question, but I can't help but think if we had a more thorough explanation of what you're trying to do, we could probably help you do it in a more straightforward way...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added more details of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep track in your `filter` callback, since you know that you'll get a call for every element of the original array and you know whether you've returned `true` or `false` for each element:

```
let indexInNewArray = 0;
let filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
    if (!item[1].includes(filter))
        return false;
    ++indexInNewArray; // Since we know we're adding to it
    if (item[1] == curr)
        idx = indexInNewArray;
    return true;
});
```

But note that `idx` will get overwritten each time you keep an entry, so you'll only know the index of the *last* entry that was kept, which you know anyway: It's `filtered.length - 1`.

---

Side note: Your sample data has numbers, not strings, in the first element of each of the subarrays, but you're using `includes` on it. `includes` is a string or array method, but not a method on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using James' findIndex answer

```
$: idx = filtered ? (index => index >= 0 ? index : 0)(filtered.findIndex((item) => item[1].every((num, index) => num === $pinned[index]))) : 0;
```